# How to dynamically change a ControlTemplate in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate

I'm trying to create a custom control which inherits from Button. In the ControlTemplate I want to display MyCustomButton as a shape like Circle, Square or any thing else.

I have a DependencyProperty - ButtonShape - which is an enumeration type and indicates the type of the shape of the button. when the user change the ButtonShape, the appearance of the button must be changed.

I know how to create a ControlTemplate for my custom button so that it could look like a circle or square or ellipse or any other shape, but I don't know what to do with the changing part.

Maybe I should create other ControlTemplates and in the OnButtenShapeChanged event set the appropriate template but I think it is not a proper way.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest way to do so would be to [define triggers in your `ControlTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.triggers%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
You'll need to define the three shapes in your (single) `ControlTemplate` and show/hide the required shapes according to the state of the `ButtonShape` property.

Comment: Additional note to the O/P: If you use Path ([doc link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.aspx)) for your shape, you can use triggers to set its Path.Data property to different geometries like circle, square, and more complex ones...

Comment: @elgonzo Good thinking. This way he also avoids unnecessary UI elements

Comment: that seems to me a good approach but what if there are more shapes? I mean if I want to have a dozen shapes that button change change it's appearance based on them, is it still a good approach?

Comment: @elgonzo thatks for your idea. that sounds better

Answer (score 0):

I'd override the `ControlTemplate` property metadata and add a Coerce callback.  Then, during the Coerce phase, return the current ControlTemplate you want to use (based on your property).

On your ButtonShape property value changed callback, you'll need to call `CoerceValue()` to update ControlTemplate.

This will disable the consumer's ability to set their own Control Template, but it sounds like that may not be an issue here.

Here's some basics on Dependency Property Coercion: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795(v=vs.110).aspx#Coerce_Value_Callbacks_and_Property_Changed_Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Coerce_Value_Callbacks_and_Property_Changed_Events)

Comment: Sorry what do you exactly mean by overriding the ControlTemplate?

Comment: Override the dependency property metadata, which allows you to add callbacks that aren't readily available otherwise. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754209(v=vs.110).aspx